# How to deserialize JSON with dynamic object?

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have a simple json, but the containing field has dynamic object. For instance, json can look like

```
{
    "fixedField1": "value1",
    "dynamicField1": {
        "f1": "abc",
        "f2": 123
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "fixedField1": "value2",
    "dynamicField1": {
        "g1": "abc",
        "g2": { "h1": "valueh1"}
    }
}
```

I am trying to serialize this object, but not sure how to map the dynamic field

```
@Serializable
data class Response(
  @SerialName("fixedField1")
  val fixedField: String,

  @SerialName("dynamicField1")
  val dynamicField: Map<String, Any> // ???? what should be the type?
)
```

Above code fails with following error

> Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation Cause:
>   Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Serializer for element of type Any has
>   not been found.

Comment: I would suggest to use Jackson library and more specifically `JsonNode` -> example usage here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object

Comment: Please take a look on `JsonObject` or `JsonElement` types. Probably it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem when I had to serialize arbitrary `Map<String, Any?>`

The only way I managed to do this so far was to use the `JsonObject`/`JsonElement` API and combining it with the `@ImplicitReflectionSerializer`

The major downside is the use of reflection which will only work properly in JVM and is not a good solution for kotlin-multiplatform.

```
    @ImplicitReflectionSerializer
    fun Map<*, *>.toJsonObject(): JsonObject = JsonObject(map {
        it.key.toString() to it.value.toJsonElement()
    }.toMap())

    @ImplicitReflectionSerializer
    fun Any?.toJsonElement(): JsonElement = when (this) {
        null -> JsonNull
        is Number -> JsonPrimitive(this)
        is String -> JsonPrimitive(this)
        is Boolean -> JsonPrimitive(this)
        is Map<*, *> -> this.toJsonObject()
        is Iterable<*> -> JsonArray(this.map { it.toJsonElement() })
        is Array<*> -> JsonArray(this.map { it.toJsonElement() })
        else -> {
            //supporting classes that declare serializers
            val jsonParser = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
            val serializer = jsonParser.context.getContextualOrDefault(this)
            jsonParser.toJson(serializer, this)
        }
    }
```

Then, to serialize you would use:

```
val response = mapOf(
    "fixedField1" to "value1",
    "dynamicField1" to mapOf (
        "f1" to "abc",
        "f2" to 123
    )
)


val serialized = Json.stringify(JsonObjectSerializer, response.toJsonObject())
```

**Note**

This reflection based serialization is only necessary if you are constrained to use `Map<String, Any?>`

If you are free to use your own DSL to build the responses, then you can use the `json` DSL directly, which is very similar to `mapOf`

```
val response1 = json {
    "fixedField1" to "value1",
    "dynamicField1" to json (
        "f1" to "abc",
        "f2" to 123
    )
}

val serialized1 = Json.stringify(JsonObjectSerializer, response1)

val response 2 = json {
    "fixedField1" to "value2",
    "dynamicField1" to json {
        "g1" to "abc",
        "g2" to json { "h1" to "valueh1"}
    }
}

val serialized2 = Json.stringify(JsonObjectSerializer, response2)
```

If, however you are constrained to define a data type, and do serialization as well as deserialization you probably can't use the `json` DSL so you'll have to define a `@Serializer` using the above methods.

An example of such a serializer, under Apache 2 license, is here: [ArbitraryMapSerializer.kt](https://github.com/uport-project/kotlin-did-jwt/blob/a34ddeb97c2debb7d855948db8c17e26a09bb9f3/jwt/src/main/java/me/uport/sdk/jwt/model/ArbitraryMapSerializer.kt)

Then you can use it on classes that have arbitrary `Map`s. In your example it would be:

```
@Serializable
data class Response(
  @SerialName("fixedField1")
  val fixedField: String,

  @SerialName("dynamicField1")
  @Serializable(with = ArbitraryMapSerializer::class)
  val dynamicField: Map<String, Any>
)
```

Comment: Update of the ArbitaryMapSerializer.kt is here: https://github.com/uport-project/kotlin-did-jwt/blob/master/jwt/src/main/java/me/uport/sdk/jwt/model/ArbitraryMapSerializer.kt

Comment: "The major downside is the use of reflection which will only work properly in JVM and is not a good solution for kotlin-multiplatform."

 Why is it not a good solution for KMM? All imports are from kotlinx.serialization which is a multiplatform solution in itself:

`import kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer 
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonElement 
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject 
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonPrimitive`

 Is there a reason that I'm not seeing? btw +1 for solution.